# Rubbish characters in Vim NERDTree

Tags: macos, ubuntu, vim, vagrant

I ran up an Ubuntu 12.04 Vagrant instance on OSX (iterm2) and am having trouble with Vim's NERDTree plugin. Seeing these garbage characters in and out of tmux. Tried setting various "term" variables on bash and in vim, but no effect.

[image: vim garbage]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your terminal cannot properly display the Unicode characters (`▾▸`) that NERD_Tree uses for the tree. As a workaround (unless you can configure your terminal to properly show those), you can revert to ASCII-style characters:

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrows = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure the `LC_ALL` environment variable is configured to use UTF-8:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: I had the same issue, I tried multiple things but this fixed it for me. Thanks!